# Using multiple credentials for same git remote address

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh

I have two git repository to push

and one is in `.ssh/config` here

```
Host git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
User AAAAAAAAAAAAA
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and another is also in `.ssh/config` this

```
#Host git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
#User BBBBBBBBBBBBB                                                                                                                            
#IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Both has the same address and different username

`git remote -v` shows like this

```
origin  ssh://git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-admin
```

When I did `git push` It will be uploaded the not-comment-out user.

So I want to switch the user in command line such as

```
git push -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa BBBBBBBBBBBBB@git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-admin
```

However it's doesn't work ( git push doesnt have -i option)

Is there any good idea to do this??

Comment: Since you’re using GIT SSH and not HTTPS you can temp use the GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment variable: `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND=“ssh -i different_private_key” git push`

Comment: [`man ssh_config`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/openssh-client/ssh_config.5.en.html#Match): **Match**. Try `Match host git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com user AAAAAAAAAAAAA` and another `Match host git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com user BBBBBBBBBBBBB`. Can be combined as `Match host git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com user AAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `git push` doesn't have `-i` option

It does not need one in your case, since the same private key, with the default name `id_rsa` is shared between the two accounts.

I would prefer using two separate keys, and Host entries much shorter, to emphasize you are using `~/.ssh/config` entries instead of a regular SSH URL:

```
Host gcaws1
  Hostname git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
  User AAAAAAAAAAAAA
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host gcaws2
  Hostname git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
  User BBBBBBBBBBBBB
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

And use URLs like:

```
origin  ssh://gcaws1/v1/repos/my-admin
# or
git push gcaws2:v1/repos/my-admin # use BBBB's key
```